# Is Facebook app submission mandatory?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

I have a mobile app on iOS and Android. I wanted to add the possibility to share something on Facebook (this can be movie details or tv program details). We have used the respective SDKs for iOS and Android and a Facebook app to do the sharing (using feed dialog). This all works ok.

My problem is related to the Facebook app review. We thought it's mandatory, but now I'm not really sure. The prerequisites for getting the app review to pass, you would need either a canvas app or use FB login in your mobile apps. We don't really have either. On canvas we could present the respective website app, but there's no FB integration. The mobile apps don't use FB login, just sharing.

But even without the succesful review, things are working ok. We can't seem to correct the FB app so that it would pass the review. The question is, do we need to have it reviewed at all to achieve the sharing functionality?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook's acceptamce policy. See [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) on [meta]

Comment: Couldn't you share like a status or does it need to be more dynamic than that? I know that that uses the persons pre-existing account details providing they have it installed on their device. Whether or not that is what you are referring to with regards to accessing and sharing details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to go through a review process for specific things. For example, if you want to ask the users for additional permissions, you need to let Facebook approved it first. Without review, only basic permissions will work (public_profile, user_friends, email).

Review is also necessary if you want to put your App in the Facebook App Center, or for Open Graph Objects/Actions.

But in general, you don´t need to go through review, especially not for using the feed dialog.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed the case. I was just able to withdraw the submission and things are fine.